# how would you calculate the number of seconds since epoch in eiffel for a DATE_TIME object

Tags: datetime, eiffel

how would you calculate the number of seconds since epoch in eiffel for a DATE_TIME object?

Comment: Isn't ist the same as https://stackoverflow.com/q/65027593/6607497 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming variable `t` is of type `DATE_TIME` (in UTC), the code to get the corresponding  number of seconds since the epoch is

```
t.definite_duration (create {DATE_TIME}.make_from_epoch (0)).seconds_count
```

*Note.* If the calculation is performed rather often, it might be more efficient to create an object `epoch` of type `DATE_TIME` with `create epoch.make_from_epoch (0)` in advance and to use it in the calculation instead:

```
t.definite_duration (epoch).seconds_count
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work:

```
make
        -- Execute the example
    local
        l_date:DATE_TIME
        l_seconds:INTEGER_64
    do
        create l_date.make_now
        l_seconds := l_date.relative_duration (create {DATE_TIME}.make_from_epoch (0)).seconds_count
        print("The number of seconds: " + l_seconds.out + "%N")
    end
```